# web scraping a certain row from a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am struggling in scraping a certain row from [this](http://www.centrometeolombardo.com/content.asp?CatId=332&ContentType=Dati) website.

First of all the table element has no class in it but I think i got a workaround to that.

My problem is that I want to print (or store in a variable or access the data) of a certain row,
Let's say the row with the first value "Bollate": [Screenshot of the row in the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FR6Qf.png)

So I coded:

```
import requests
import bs4

URL = "http://www.centrometeolombardo.com/content.asp?CatId=332&ContentType=Dati"

response = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

table = soup.find(text="Bollate").find_parent("table")

for a in table:
    if a.text == "Bollate":
       for val in a.parent-find_next_siblings():
           print(val.text)
```

But I get getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Python/ngu.py", line 12, in <module>
   if a.text == "Bollate":
  File "/usr/lib/Python3/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 370, in _getattr_
   self._class_._name_, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Which suggests me I am wrong since I get something that is not a text but I do not know how to overcome the problem.

Thanks all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup tag is type bs4.element.NavigableString and bs4.element.Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879839/beautifulsoup-tag-is-type-bs4-element-navigablestring-and-bs4-element-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to grab the `HTML` and parse the table. Then just select the value you need.

Here's how:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "http://www.centrometeolombardo.com/content.asp?CatId=332&ContentType=Dati"
df = pd.read_html(url, flavor="bs4")[19]
print(df.loc[df[0] == "Bollate"])
```

Output:

```
         0     1     2      3  4  5
2  Bollate  -0.3  12.3  Brina  -  -
```

Comment: Thanks!!
I am reading throug pd documentation but I just do not get the [19], what is that for?

Comment: `pd.read_html()` returns a list of tables. The one that has the value you're looking for is 19th out of 25 tables there.

Comment: clear.
If I am searching for another row, avoiding the [19] would search in all the tables gotten with pd?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. As I've said, you have a list of tables, so you can either concatenate all of them into one (not recommended in this case) or loop thru the list and pick the one you want. This will print all the tables that `pandas` has successfully parsed: `print(pd.read_html(url, flavor="bs4"))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can isolate the row with :contains and :has to ensure b tag with that text within a tr. You also need to target the right nested table e.g. with nth-child

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_source = requests.get('http://www.centrometeolombardo.com/content.asp?CatId=332&ContentType=Dati').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
print([td.get_text(strip=True) for td in soup.select('div:nth-child(5) table:nth-child(3) tr:has(b:contains("Bollate")) td')])
```

---

Thanks to @SIM for pointing out one could avoid hardcoding an index by using the following pattern instead:

```
soup.select("table > tr:has(> td > a:contains('Bollate')) td")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

May I ask  why  'div:nth-child(5) table:nth-child(3)   ?

I do not get the meaning of this part
Thx

Comment: There are nested table. :has needs to select for the actual direct parent table not any parents further up the DOM

Comment: Ok that's perfect!
What if the position of the table in the page changes?
Would I need to change the 3 to the update value?
would a for get the job done?

Comment: you would need to review the html.

Comment: I think this is one of the ways we can kick out harcoded index to reach the desired content `soup.select("table > tr:has(> td > a:contains('Bollate')) td")` @QHarr.

Comment: Thanks @SIM. I should prolly have spent more time looking into it.

Comment: @SIM

Thank you, now works and it s easier to handle,
I store an array with 

'''soup.select("table > tr:has(> td > a:contains('Bollate')) td")'''

thx

Comment: Glad you found it useful @mant0 . To let you know, It is QHarr who once introduced me to the usage of `:has()`. Thanks.