# How to scrape match data with its corresponding date?

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to scrape a website for Cricket club results, but the number of matches on a certain date are not fixed. Eg: Saturday 17 September 2022 has 1 match, and Saturday 10 September 2022 has 3 matches. It would've been simple if the website separated the dates in different classes or tables but it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
import requests
import urllib3
import pandas as pd
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

The URL for the website as shown below:-

```
#Url = Page 1 of results
url = 'https://halstead.play-cricket.com/Matches?fixture_month=13&home_or_away=both&page=1&q%5Bcategory_id%5D=all&q%5Bgender_id%5D=all&search_in=&season_id=255&seasonchange=f&selected_season_id=255&tab=Result&team_id=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&view_by=year'

data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
```

Main Code

```
#Creating the table
main_lists = {'Team A':[], '':[],'Team B':[]}
entries = soup.findAll('p', class_='txt1')
list = []

for entries in entries:
    #Everything in one list
    list.append(entries.text.strip('/n'))

#Separating entries by odd and even index
l = range(len(list))
list_even = list[::2]
list_odd = list [1::2]

for list_even in list_even:
    main_lists['Team A'] += [list_even]
    main_lists[''] += ['vs']
for list_odd in list_odd:
    main_lists['Team B'] += [list_odd]

#Turn lists into dataframe
df_main = pd.DataFrame(main_lists)

#Getting result
res_list = []
x = 0
while x < df_main.shape[0]:
    res = soup.select('.fonts-gt')[x];x += 1
    res_list.append(res.text)
    res_list = [sub.replace('  ',' ') for sub in res_list]

df_main['Result'] = res_list
df_main = df_main.reindex(columns=['Result', 'Team A', 'Team B'])

#Getting the Date
date = soup.findAll('div', class_='col-sm-12 text-center text-md-left title2 padding_top_for_mobile')

date_table = []
for date in date:
    date_table.append(date.text.strip('\n'))
    date_table2 = [sub.replace('2022\n', '2022') for sub in date_table]
df_date = pd.DataFrame(date_table2)

print(f'The length of df_main is {len(df_main)}, and the length of df_date is {len(df_date)}')
```

Here we can see the difference in number of rows of both data frames.

> The length of df_main is 25, and the length of df_date is 12

I did try using something like:-

```
items = soup.find_all(class_=['row ml-large-0 mr-large-0','col-sm-12 d-md-none match-status-mobile'])
for item in items:
    print(item.text)
```

[Which gives something like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMsOi.png)
But I still have no idea how to separate these by the date.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your selection strategy and extract information in one go. Iterate over the matches and use [`find_previous()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous) to extract the respective date under which the match is listed.

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://halstead.play-cricket.com/Matches?fixture_month=13&home_or_away=both&page=1&q%5Bcategory_id%5D=all&q%5Bgender_id%5D=all&search_in=&season_id=255&seasonchange=f&selected_season_id=255&tab=Result&team_id=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&view_by=year'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
data = []

for e in soup.select('table'):
    d = dict(zip(['Team A','Team B'],[t.text for t in e.select('.txt1')]))
    d.update({
        'Result':e.div.text,
        'Date':e.find_previous('div',class_='title2').get_text(strip=True)
    })
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | Team A | Team B | Result | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Halstead CC, Essex - 1st XI | Fakenham CC - 1st XI | FAKENHAM CC WON BY 8 WICKETS | Saturday 17 September 2022 |
| 1 | Battisford & District CC - Saturday 1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex - 2nd XI | CANCELLED | Saturday 10 September 2022 |
| 2 | Maldon CC - 4th XI | Halstead CC, Essex - 3rd XI | CANCELLED | Saturday 10 September 2022 |
| 3 | Halstead CC, Essex - 1st XI | Worlington CC - 1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 23 RUNS | Saturday 10 September 2022 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 21 | Halstead CC, Essex - NECL 1st XI | Wickham St Pauls CC - 1st XI | WICKHAM ST PAULS CC WON BY 2 WICKETS | Sunday 31 July 2022 |
| 22 | Halstead CC, Essex - 2nd XI | West Bergholt CC - Two Counties 1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 3 RUNS | Saturday 30 July 2022 |
| 23 | Halstead CC, Essex - 3rd XI | Abberton & District CC - 3rd XI | ABBERTON & DISTRICT CC WON BY 6 WICKETS | Saturday 30 July 2022 |
| 24 | Coggeshall Town CC - 1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex - 1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 117 RUNS | Saturday 30 July 2022 |

Answer (score 0):

It was difficult, but, once I change the approach to get the data, I could get the results you want.

The changes were:

- Get the data inside the `table` HTML element - which is the element that has the matches (*i.e. Team A, Team B and result*) .
- For the *date*, get the text inside the `div` when this said `div` **does not have a `table` HTML element**.

Here is the modified code:

```
import requests
import urllib3
import pandas as pd
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Url = Page 1 of results
url = 'https://halstead.play-cricket.com/Matches?fixture_month=13&home_or_away=both&page=1&q%5Bcategory_id%5D=all&q%5Bgender_id%5D=all&search_in=&season_id=255&seasonchange=f&selected_season_id=255&tab=Result&team_id=&utf8=%E2%9C%93&view_by=year'
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

# Variables: 
result_array = [] # It will contain the list of dictionaries with the desired data.
team_a = "" # Value for "Team A" column.
team_b = "" # Value for "Team B" column.
result = "" # Value for "Result" column. 
temp_date = "" # Stores the date.

# Get the main div that contains the data to extract: 
div_principal = soup.find("div", class_="tab-pane fade active in")

# Loop the divs "i.e. the data of the matches and the date" found in the main container div: 
for indx, div in enumerate(div_principal):
  # Loop only the valid elements with the data to get:
  if (indx >= 5 and indx <= 77): 
    # Check if the element is a valid BeautifulSoup "Tag" element: 
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42802393/12511801
    if type(div) is bs4.element.Tag: 
      # If no "table" is found on this div, then, it's a "date" - that's due I'm getting the "data" contained on the "table" HTML element: 
      if (div.find("table") is not None):
        # Get the values for "Team A", "Team B" and "Result": 
        team_a = div.find('table').find("p", class_="txt1").get_text("", strip=True)
        team_b = div.find('table').find("td", class_="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3 text-center text-md-left card-table-r bgGray").find("p", class_="txt1").get_text("", strip=True)
        # Here the original text has double spaces. 
        # Example: FAKENHAM CC WON  BY 8 WICKETS 
        # (notice the double spaces between the words "WON" and "BY"). 
        result = div.find('table').find("div", class_="fonts-gt").get_text("", strip=True).replace("  ", " ") # <== Here 
      else: 
        # Get the "date" and clear the other variables: 
        temp_date = div.get_text("", strip=True)
        team_a = ""
        team_b = ""
        result = ""
    # Add elements to the list:
    if (len(team_a) > 0):
      result_array.append({"Team A" : team_a, "Team B": team_b, "Result": result, "Date": temp_date})

# Remove duplicates - source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9427216/12511801
result_array = [i for n, i in enumerate(result_array) if i not in result_array[n + 1:]]

# Build and display dataframe:
df_final = pd.DataFrame(result_array)
display(df_final)
```

Result:

| index | Team A | Team B | Result | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | Fakenham CC-1st XI | FAKENHAM CC WON BY 8 WICKETS | Saturday 17 September 2022 |
| 1 | Battisford & District CC-Saturday 1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-2nd XI | CANCELLED | Saturday 10 September 2022 |
| 2 | Maldon CC-4th XI | Halstead CC, Essex-3rd XI | CANCELLED | Saturday 10 September 2022 |
| 3 | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | Worlington CC-1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 23 RUNS | Saturday 10 September 2022 |
| 4 | Halstead CC, Essex-2nd XI | Dunmow CC-2nd XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 25 RUNS | Saturday 03 September 2022 |
| 5 | Mistley CC-1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 4 WICKETS | Saturday 03 September 2022 |
| 6 | Halstead CC, Essex-NECL T20 | Coggeshall Town CC-NECL T20 | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 90 RUNS | Sunday 28 August 2022 |
| 7 | Halstead CC, Essex-NECL T20 | Mistley CC-NECL T20 | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 152 RUNS | Sunday 28 August 2022 |
| 8 | Halstead CC, Essex-2nd XI | Stowupland CC-1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 7 WICKETS | Saturday 27 August 2022 |
| 9 | Halstead CC, Essex-3rd XI | Real Oddies CC-1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 6 WICKETS | Saturday 27 August 2022 |
| 10 | Kesgrave CC-1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 7 WICKETS | Saturday 27 August 2022 |
| 11 | Sudbury CC, Suffolk-Sunday 1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-NECL 1st XI | SUDBURY CC, SUFFOLK WON BY 22 RUNS | Sunday 21 August 2022 |
| 12 | St Margaret's CC, Suffolk-1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-2nd XI | ST MARGARET'S CC, SUFFOLK WON BY 60 RUNS | Saturday 20 August 2022 |
| 13 | Kelvedon and Feering CC-2nd XI | Halstead CC, Essex-3rd XI | KELVEDON AND FEERING CC WON BY 1 WICKET | Saturday 20 August 2022 |
| 14 | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | Woolpit CC-Saturday 1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 6 WICKETS | Saturday 20 August 2022 |
| 15 | Halstead CC, Essex-2nd XI | Mildenhall CC, Suffolk-4th XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 8 WICKETS | Saturday 13 August 2022 |
| 16 | Halstead CC, Essex-3rd XI | Witham CC-3rd XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 9 WICKETS | Saturday 13 August 2022 |
| 17 | Wivenhoe Town CC-1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 3 WICKETS | Saturday 13 August 2022 |
| 18 | Halstead CC, Essex-NECL 1st XI | Colchester and East Essex CC-NECL 1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 5 WICKETS | Sunday 07 August 2022 |
| 19 | Ipswich CC-1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-2nd XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 1 RUN | Saturday 06 August 2022 |
| 20 | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | Clacton On Sea CC-Saturday XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 9 WICKETS | Saturday 06 August 2022 |
| 21 | Halstead CC, Essex-NECL 1st XI | Wickham St Pauls CC-1st XI | WICKHAM ST PAULS CC WON BY 2 WICKETS | Sunday 31 July 2022 |
| 22 | Halstead CC, Essex-2nd XI | West Bergholt CC-Two Counties 1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 3 RUNS | Saturday 30 July 2022 |
| 23 | Halstead CC, Essex-3rd XI | Abberton & District CC-3rd XI | ABBERTON & DISTRICT CC WON BY 6 WICKETS | Saturday 30 July 2022 |
| 24 | Coggeshall Town CC-1st XI | Halstead CC, Essex-1st XI | HALSTEAD CC, ESSEX WON BY 117 RUNS | Saturday 30 July 2022 |